# Invalid date supplied in teradata--varchar date to timestamp(0)

Tags: teradata

I have a date column in source which is defined as varchar(255). I want to convert that to timestamp(0). I am using the below query:

```
SEL CAST(CAST( SERIND AS CHAR(10)) || ' 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0))
FROM DP_BOX.SOC1
WHERE SERIND ='20130518'
```

I am getting invalid timestamp here. Sample SERIND are

```
20170509
00000000
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `CAST` with correct format of `TIMESTAMP(0)`

```
SEL CAST(SERIND as TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')
FROM DP_BOX.SOC1;
```

Comment: Nope, its giving invalid timestamp. :(

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to `CAST()` your way to a date format that is acceptable as a component of a timestamp in Teradata. (I think there may be a shortcut with math to get to a numeric format as well but I have to noodle on that one.)

Assuming SERIND is CHAR(8) to begin with. The first `CAST()` gets you to a `DATE` value with a compatible format. The second `CAST()` gets you a `DATE` with 10 character format so that when you concatenate it to the `TIME` portion of the timestamp the resulting character conversion of the `DATE` value is in the correct 10 character format to be explicitly `CAST()` into a `TIMESTAMP` value:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(SERIND AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') 
              AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) 
  FROM DP_BOX.SOC1
 WHERE SERIND > '00000000'; -- Invalid Date value
```

Comment: You can do this in one step:  `select cast(serind as timestamp(0) format 'YYYYMMDD')`.

Comment: @Rob Tried that approach but still giving invalid date :(

Comment: @andrew Not working as i have 00000000 as well in my date field.

Comment: @user3901666  you have to exclude 00000000. It is not a valid date literal in Teradata. If you have other values that are not valid, it will require additional logic